# Como girar personaje en unity con mando de ps4?

Tags: unity3d

estoy realizando el movimiento de mi jugador con un mando de ps4, pero no logro hacer que gire en torno al joystick, si alguien tiene una idea que me diga muchas gracias

```
    float a = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float b= Input.GetAxis("Vertical");


    float tang = Mathf.Atan2(b, a);
    float grados = tang * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

    rigg.transform.Rotate(0, grados * Time.deltaTime, 0);
```

esto hice probando algo que vi en internet pero no gira ni medianamente bien, nuca e usado mando de ps4 por eso estoy perdido de como funciona

Comment: Hola @Jose, hay varios videos en youtube,webs, incluso en el propio [foro](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1387259/joystick-character-movement.html) de unity hay ya hechos algun que otro post. Prueba el codigo que encuentres y si aun asi tienes dudas , vuelve con el codigo que hayas probado y estaremos encantados de ayudarte

Comment: como estas  Victor Manuel, ya busque en youtube y en la web pero no hay nada que use el joystick de un mando para girar, por eso pregunte porque no se me viene nada  a la cabeza de como hacer

Comment: @josemoya creo que obtendras mejor resultado si haces tu pregunta en [gamedev.stackexchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)